# XML to Table in R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe, data-manipulation

How do I convert the data from this xml: "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/nfl-t1/2013/REG/1/statistics.xml?api_key=4dhyq3f3rfkp2cbm4yqbcuag" into a table.

I have this code so far, and R reads the XML file properly... but I want to turn it into a table to make my analysis easier:

```
library(XML)
fileURL <-  "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/nfl-t1/2013/REG/1/statistics.xml?api_key=4dhyq3f3rfkp2cbm4yqbcuag"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL, useInternal = TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
xmlName(rootNode)
```

When I use xmlToDataFrame, I get a dataframe with no values... I have tried several approaches, but none of these work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The data is not in tabular form. Can you elaborate on "I want to turn it into a table"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmlToList` to turn the `XML` into an R list. The data is not in a form which is readily convertible to a table. You would need to elaborate further what quantities are required in a tabular form.

```
library(XML)
fileURL <-  "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/nfl-t1/2013/REG/1/statistics.xml?api_key=4dhyq3f3rfkp2cbm4yqbcuag"
xData <- xmlParse(fileURL)
appData <- xmlToList(xData)
> names(appData[[1]][[1]])
[1] "touchdowns"             "third_down_efficiency"  "rushing"               
[4] "redzone_efficiency"     "receiving"              "punting"               
[7] "punt_return"            "penalty"                "passing"               
[10] "kickoffs"               "goal_efficiency"        "fumbles"               
[13] "fourth_down_efficiency" "first_downs"            "extra_point"           
[16] "defense"                ".attrs"
```

As an example of how you might approach extracting sections of the data into tabular format we can look at the first game in the data set and the defense stats by player for the first team

```
library(XML)
fileURL <-  "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/nfl-t1/2013/REG/1/statistics.xml?api_key=4dhyq3f3rfkp2cbm4yqbcuag"
xData <- xmlParse(fileURL)
defData <- xpathApply(xData, 
                      path = "//ns:games/ns:game[1]/ns:team[1]/ns:defense/ns:player"
                      , namespaces= c(ns = "http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/nfl/statistics-v1.0.xsd")
                      , xmlToList)
outData <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, defData)
names(outData) <- names(defData[[1]])
head(outData)

> head(outData)
                                    id               name jersey position tackle ast comb tlost sack
1 06b8c3d2-0d20-452e-86fc-69a7a269cd44    Kevin Vickerson     99       DT      2   0    2     1  0.0
2 99149c69-e14f-4e05-9c3a-8ae7e3b1f00b       Aaron Brewer     46       LS      0   0    0     0  0.0
3 d15dacdb-17c6-4010-83d1-e332f9610422 Sylvester Williams     92       DT      1   0    1     1  0.0
4 ca6c6bb5-9ab9-4b4c-a507-36c9dbd7738e        Nate Irving     56       LB      3   1    4     1  0.0
5 252da24d-9eb7-4871-ae76-199918f412d8      Malik Jackson     97       DE      0   1    1     0  0.0
6 d867198a-36ec-4a99-9037-a093216f99d8       Mitch Unrein     96       DT      1   0    1     0  0.0
  sack_yds sfty int int_yds int_lg int_td force_fum fum_rec fum_td qh pd bk sp_tackle sp_ast sp_comb
1      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         0      0       0
2      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         1      0       1
3      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         0      0       0
4      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         0      0       0
5      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         0      0       0
6      0.0    0   0       0      0      0         0       0      0  0  0  0         0      0       0
  sp_force_fum sp_fum_rec misc_tackle misc_ast misc_comb misc_force_fum misc_fum_rec
1            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
2            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
3            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
4            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
5            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
6            0          0           0        0         0              0            0
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, and I got this error: "Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "character" "

Comment: @user2963483 there was a typo `doc` has been changed to `path` and the code should work now

Answer (score 1):

After spending nearly 2 days trying all kinds of difficult methods, these two lines simply worked without any issues.

First, define this function

```
xml_to_dataframe <- function(nodeset){
 if(class(nodeset) != 'xml_nodeset'){
   stop('Input should be "xml_nodeset" class')
 }
 lst <- lapply(nodeset, function(x){
   tmp <- xml2::xml_text(xml2::xml_children(x))
   names(tmp) <- xml2::xml_name(xml2::xml_children(x))
   return(as.list(tmp))
 })
 result <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(lst, function(x)
   as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = F)))
 return(dplyr::as_tibble(result))
}
```

And now you should be able to take any XML and turn it into a data frame

```
xml_df <- read_xml("your-file-path.xml")

parsed_xml <- xml_children(xml_df) %>% xml_to_dataframe()
```

I hope this works for others!